# how to use smilies with codes[i.e :-) ] in angular.js??

Tags: javascript, angularjs, emoji, angular-ng

I am looking to attach smiles to my messages on a application.
But I am unable to find the smiles in angular.js .
I am finding some like :smile: then the symbol comes.
But I want this to be done with codes like :-) , :-( then a smile and sad symbols needs to come respectively.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try to replace them. Just like: replace `:-)` with `<img src="/smileys/happy.png" />`, replace `:-(` with `<img src="/smileys/sad.png" />`

Comment: What are you using to transform `:smile:` to emojis? Can you give more details about this "application"? Show us some code :)

Comment: I am looking for a plugin in as I have many in jquery in this way but not in angular.js

Answer (score 1):

You will need to look for a angular module that adds emoji autocomeplete for textareas.

A couple of examples that may suit your need:

- https://github.com/globaldev/angular-emoji-filter -- [[DEMO]](http://dev.venntro.com/angular-emoji-filter/)
- https://github.com/terranisu/angular-emoji-picker

Comment: I want the smiles to show when i type :-) .. I am getting this :smile: but I am looking for these :-) codes in angular.js

Answer (score 0):

You are seeing them come through with :smile: because that's the emoji code for smily face.

Take a look at http://www.emoji-cheat-sheet.com/

But if you really wanted to you could write a angular filter that would replace anywhere you saw a ":-)" with a :smile: and then the other filters would render the emoji as you'd expect.

Comment: I want the smiles to show when i type :-) .. I am getting this :smile: but I am looking for these :-) codes in angular.js